# Loading native library from internet via Java

Tags: java, dynamic, native

i saw that `System.load` and `System.loadLibrary` are able (and used) to load a native library for different purpuses.

Is there a way to load the native library from internet instead as local file? Maybe with bytes or something?

Like:

`System.load(new URL("http://example.com/mylibrary.dll"))` or `System.load(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 })`

If thats not possible with default Java, is there a library which can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: The docs say the string argument must be a filename, so I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Furthermore, this would only be possible on most operating systems by first downloading the library to a file and then mapping it in anyway.

Comment: Well yes, but i think in some ways, with some tricks should be able to. Just think about ClassLoader, you can load a Class from internet or via bytes.. isnt a DLL just a file? So isnt a File a bouch of bytes? It should be possible somehow